# ViewModel Singleton With Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, koin, android-koin

One of the objects that I am trying to inject captures a references in a lambda. That lambda is used as a callback to update my viewModel. How can I use koin to inject that object?

Working code that does not use dependency injection for:

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()
private val barcodeDataReceiver =
    BarcodeDataReceiver {
        viewModel.addItem(it)
    }
```

I would ideally like to create my `BarcodeDataReceiver` with `koin`, but when I use `get<MyViewModel>()` I am getting a new instance of `MyViewModel`. I know that `koin`'s `viewModel { }` is a factory, but is there any way to get a singleton?

I tried wrapping `viewModel { }` with `single { }` but that doesn't work.